# Calculate visibility of single point

Tags: qgis, viewshed, visibility

I am looking to identify where a single point in the landscape can be seen from everywhere else in the landscape. Specifically, I want to know from where a hypothetical 34m building can be seen from in a landscape.

I can see that the current visibility analysis tools allow me to calculate what can be seen from the point, but not the other way around.

Is it as simple as reversing the observer height/target height, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: If you calculate, what can be seen from that point 34 m above ground, you also calculate, from where that point can be seen, don't you?

Comment: @Erik Yeah I thought that to begin with, but it would be rendered differently for a view in rather than a view out, there would be massive overlap but it's not quite the same

Comment: How is it not quite the same? If there is a line of sight from A to B, there is a line of sight from B to A. Therefore it must be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the viewshed analysis plugin. It is done exactly for what you need:
[viewshed analysis](https://landscapearchaeology.org/qgis-visibility-analysis/)
If you set the point to the correct height (building), and set the above ground to 1.85cm (person)!